# is it a good idea to have container class that keeps global data?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm trying to find a way to hold all the php application data at one place.
For example,get and post parameters, page titles, pagination results, etc. to avoid using global variables.

Is this a good idea to keep all data and exchange between contollers in a following object?

```
class container {

protected static $_instance;
protected $_instance_class;

public static function instance($instance_name = 'default')
{
    $c = __CLASS__;

    if ( ! isset($c::$_instance[$instance_name]))
    {
        $c::$_instance[$instance_name] = new $c();
        $c::$_instance[$instance_name]->_instance_class = $instance_name;
    }
    return $c::$_instance[$instance_name];
}

public function set($key, $val)
{
    // someting like $this->$key = $val;
}

public function get($key)
{
    // someting like retrun $this->$key;
}

}
```

and then, for example in model

```
container::instance('messages')->set('error', 'some error');
```

and in the controller or view

```
container::instance('messages')->get('error');
```

Or is there any other way to keep data accessible from everywhere in the app?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talked about is called [Registry pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) (and another [good article](http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/basic/practical-php-patterns-0) on it). While it has some disadvantages (for example, to test a method that fetches some data from Registry we have to mock this Registry as well), it's definitely better than using global variables or Singletons.

In fact, in Zend Framework 1 this pattern is implemented [quite literally](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.registry.html):

```
// setting a value (usually done in Bootstrap)
Zend_Registry::set('index', $value);

// getting a value (usually in actions and/or models)
$value = Zend_Registry::get('index');
```

To show what can be wrong with this approach, let's analyze the following:

```
class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function barAction() {
        $baz = Zend_Registry::get('baz');
        $model = new Some_Model($baz); 
        ...
    }
}
```

The question is simple: what's that `$baz` thing here? Is it an object? Or array? Or some other beast, like function or resource? You have to rely on comments here, and that's usually not a good thing - unless you're working with trivial and common objects (like query params, or database resource objects).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with having hard-coded references to static classes *for things of this nature* is that you're creating tight dependency on those static classes. If you decide to change the source of your "global" properties in the future, you have an application littered with references to that source.

A much better approach, if you want a somewhat global property entity, is to create something that you will instantiate, and give an interface that tailors to what your application needs. For the sake of argument, let's call this interface `GlobalConfigurationProvider`. Then your application code could expect (and depend on) some implementation of `GlobalConfigurationProvider`. Now if you change the way you implement configuration in the future, you only have to worry about the new element--the new instance of `GlobalConfigurationProvider`, instead of all of the classes, views, etc. where you're referencing a configuration provider.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a global container class, consider programming OO and keep methods and variables together in 1 class.

In your error example, the error belongs to a class, and should kept there.

References to your class could be held by a global Registry, or, nicer, by a IoC container.